Nginx docker file upload permission denied
I have an Nginx docker container, configured in a docker-compose file like so:
my-nginx:
  image: nginx:1.26.0
  container_name: my-nginx
  hostname: my-nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
    - x.x.x.x:8001:6001
  networks:
    - public
  volumes:
    - "/opt/docker/volumes/nginx-html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    - "/opt/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    - "/opt/docker/volumes/logs/nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx/logs"
    - "/opt/docker/volumes/certs:/etc/certificates/nginx"

The nginx.conf has nothing special in it, no proxying, just serving HTML/JS/CSS/IMG files from two local folders:
server {
    listen       6001 ssl;
    server_name  my-nginx;
    ssl_certificate /etc/certificates/nginx/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certificates/nginx/my.decrypted.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html/site1;
        index   index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.html;
    }

    location /site2 {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/site2;
        index   my.js;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/my.js;
    }

    location /site1 {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/site1;
        index   index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.html;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/logs/error.log warn;

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

This is working very well, no problems. The HTML files are correctly found and served from the mounted volume folder, as well as the config and the cert files are loaded. The log folder is also mounted as a volume, and I can see the log files access.log and error.log created successfully.
I added a new folder called external_images under the /opt/docker/volumes/nginx-html folder, which is supposed to act as an upload folder for image files (from a trusted internal source). I put this new folder to the other html source folder because these same images will need to be served to other clients through HTTP. The new upload interface config looks like this:
location ~ "/upload/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$" {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/external_images/$1;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp;
    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    create_full_put_path on;
    dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
    client_body_in_file_only on;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    limit_except PUT OPTIONS HEAD { deny all; }
}

I cannot get this to work, for the life of me. I keep getting permission denied errors:
curl -T test.png https://x.x.x.x:8001/upload/

2024/06/17 16:36:35 [crit] 21#21: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/external_images/test.png.0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied), client: y.y.y.y, server: my-nginx, request: "PUT /upload/test.png HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x:8001"

When I connect to the container, I'm internally root, so I can write into files in this folder without issues:
[admin@server docker]$ sudo docker exec -it my-nginx bash
root@voda-nginx:/# echo aaa > /usr/share/nginx/html/external_images/test.png.0000000002
root@voda-nginx:/# exit
exit

[admin@server docker]$ ll volumes/nginx-html/external_images/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4 Jun 17 18:52 test.png.0000000002
[admin@server docker]$ cat volumes/nginx-html/external_images/test.png.0000000002
aaa

But when I try to do the same in the name of the internal "nginx" user, I get permission denied:
root@my-nginx:/# su -s /bin/bash -c "echo aaa > /usr/share/nginx/html/external_images/test.png.0000000002" - nginx
-bash: line 1: /usr/share/nginx/html/external_images/test.png.0000000002: Permission denied

I tried the same with the log folder, where the log files are already being written by nginx successfully, and even there I couldn't create the new file as the "nginx" user.
What am I missing?

Edit: adding environment details
The docker is running on RedHat 8.9, with SELinux enabled, but I don't think it is a SELinux issue, because we have a bunch of containers running, each of them write log files and even custom CSV files and other into volume folders without problems.

So the solution was simpler than I thought... I went into the docker container bash, chown-ed the /usr/share/nginx/html folder for nginx user and group, and it started working. I then checked externally on the OS, and saw that the volume folder is now owned by user and group ID 101, so I created nginx user and group as ID 101 and now it's working. I can recreate the container and there is no need to chown it again internally.
